# Suspend container on AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-fargate

I'm planning deploying Docker containers using AWS Elastic Container Service on Fargate.

I could'nt find any valuable information regarding docker containers being paused and the associated billing.

Is it possible to pause Docker containers on Fargate so that one can save CPU/memory bill ? The use case is using containers from time to time, but not wanting to respawn new containers, just pause and resume existing one.
Something like DigitalOcean's snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably already saw on the [Task Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_life_cycle.html), there is no `PAUSED` state, so no, it's not possible to pause and resume Tasks.

The best approach is to define an **autoscaling policy** that manages for you the active Tasks, and that's perfect to save on CPU/Memory bill.

Since your use case needs these containers from time to time, the trick is to define "how can I understand when I need them". For example, you could push something into a SQS queue and spawn 2 Tasks only when there is at least 1 element in the queue. Once it was processed, the autoscaling policy will terminate the Task and you will not pay anything at all.

Using CloudFormation, you could define your target service like this:

```
ECSTarget:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
  Properties:
    MaxCapacity: 2
    MinCapacity: 0
    ResourceId: !Join ["/", [service, !Ref MyCluster, !GetAtt [MyService, Name]]]
    RoleARN: !GetAtt [ EcsAutoScalingRole, Arn ]
    ScalableDimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount
    ServiceNamespace: ecs
```

Define the rules for scaling up and down

```
ECSScaleUp:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyName: !Join ['-', ['MyService', 'ScaleUpPolicy']]
    PolicyType: StepScaling
    ScalingTargetId: !Ref ECSTarget
    StepScalingPolicyConfiguration:
      Cooldown: 30
      MetricAggregationType: "Average"
      AdjustmentType: "ExactCapacity"
      StepAdjustments:
        - MetricIntervalLowerBound: 0
          ScalingAdjustment: 2

ECSScaleDown:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyName: !Join ['-', ['MyService', 'ScaleDownPolicy']]
    PolicyType: StepScaling
    ScalingTargetId: !Ref ECSTarget
    StepScalingPolicyConfiguration:
      Cooldown: 30
      MetricAggregationType: "Average"
      AdjustmentType: "ExactCapacity"
      StepAdjustments:
        - MetricIntervalUpperBound: -1
          ScalingAdjustment: 0
```

And then define an Alarm to trigger the autoscaling

```
ECSSQSAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    AlarmName: !Join ['-', [!Ref 'MyService', 'SQSAlarm']]
    AlarmDescription: "Trigger ECS Service Scaling based on SQS queue"
    Namespace: "AWS/SQS"
    MetricName: "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"
    ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanThreshold"
    Dimensions:
      - Name: QueueName
        Value: !GetAtt [ MyQueue, QueueName]
    EvaluationPeriods: 2
    Period: 60
    Statistic: 'Average'
    Threshold: 1
    AlarmActions:
      - !Ref ECSWorkerScaleUp
      - !Ref ECSWorkerScaleDown
    OKActions:
      - !Ref ECSWorkerScaleUp
      - !Ref ECSWorkerScaleDown
```